# How to filter entire dataset after $lookup aggregate operation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections:

```
user ( userID, liveID )
```

```
live ( liveID )
```

I want to get all **lives** with a count of how many users have the corresponding **liveID** associated. This is simple, here is what I did:

```js
db.getCollection('live').aggregate([
        { $match: { /* whatever if needed */ }},
        { $lookup: {
            from: 'user',
            localField: 'liveID',
            foreignField: 'liveID',
            as: 'count'
        }},
        { $addFields: { 'count': { $size: '$count' }}}, // I do this since I don't want the results, just the count
    ]
);
```

This query is pretty fast and in a dataset of 10,000 **lives** and 10,000 **users** it takes roughly **0.031** seconds.

Now, I need to filter the results and just get **lives** where its **count** value is greater than zero. I tried adding a simple **$match** operation on my pipeline as `{ $match: { 'count': { $gt : 0 }}}` and it increases significantly the operation time up to **1.91** seconds.

I figured that I'm probably doing something non optimal here, I tried using **$project**, however it only allows me to modify the item and not completely remove it from the final dataset. I also found some examples using **$lookup** pipelines, but I couldn't create a query that works.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Try starting from `user` instead, with $group, then $lookup from live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a `$addFields` to get the size of the `count` array field and then `$match` to filter the documents with size greater than zero - you can combine both the stages as a single `$match` stage. The [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator allows using Aggregation operators with the `$match` stage (and also within the `find` method). Using the `$expr` build the `$match` stage as follows:

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: "$count" }, 0 ] } } }
```

This stage will follow the `$lookup` in the pipeline. Doing work in lesser stages in a pipeline is a best practice as well as it improves performance especially when the number of documents being processed are large.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there is no improvement at all...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many `live` would match your initial condition, it might be better to find the users first. Then join with the live and match it later

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$liveID',
      count: { $sum: 1 } // if you need the count
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'live',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'liveID',
      as: 'live'
   }
},
{
  $unwind: '$live'
}, {
  $replaceRoot: { $newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ['$live', { count: '$count' }] }
}, {
  $match: { /* whatever if needed */ }
}]);
```

Comment: yes, that would work, that's actually the solution I came up with, however I'd like to understand why the `$match` I added at the bottom of my query caused so much performance drawback.

Comment: Because `$size` does not use any index and needs the full result scan to compare with 0